# How to migrate php preg_replace to preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, regex

Given line:

```
"$className = "MForm" . preg_replace('/(?:^|_)(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')",$name);"
```

isn't working with PHP7.  I changed it to:

```
"$className = "MForm" . preg_replace_callback('/(?:^|_)(.?)/',"strtoupper('$1')",$name);"
```

It seems not to be correct, due to warning printout:

> "Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'strtoupper('$1')', to be a valid callback in /.../components/com_proforms/formlib/init.php on line 59"

How can I handle `strtoupper('$1')` correctly in preg_replace_callback()?

Comment: You need to pass the name of a function so that it can be executed later. Whereas Ylyou're passing the _result_ of already executing that function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 1):

Replace "strtoupper('$1')" with

`function($matches) { return strtoupper($matches[1]); }`

No quotes around it.

Comment: Thank you @dehart, the closing bracket was missing. So it's correct: 



function($matches) { return strtoupper($matches[1]); }